# Chrome - Ajax fails to load on refresh

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

I'm loading in content using Ajax from a JSON file, injecting into the HTML. The first time the page loads in chrome and all fine, if you click the refresh button on the chrome browser it loads again fine, however when you click enter on the address bar, it seems to fail to load the content. It is only happening in Chrome, how can I fix that? Is it something to do with cache?

```
function loadContent(){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: "json/de-de/content.json",
        data: "nocache=" + Math.random(),
        type: "GET",
        cache : true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(source){
            data = source;
            jsonTxtLoad(data);
            $('.json-delay').animate({opacity:1});

        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("failed to load")

        }
    }); 

}
```

Comment: Have you wrapped your `loadContent` function in a `$(document).ready( function () {})` ?

Comment: yes I did it's wrapped in a $(document).ready( function () {}) and a  $(window).load(function(){

Comment: hmm I think you should split the whole thing up into smaller functions, it would make it easier to determine what the problem is. you should move the success function and the error function into separate functions and simply pass the function as an object to the success, error arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap without loadContent function. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "json/de-de/content.json",
        data: "nocache=" + Math.random(),
        type: "GET",
        cache : true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(source){
            data = source;
            jsonTxtLoad(data);
            $('.json-delay').animate({opacity:1});

    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log("failed to load")

        }
 });
```

});

Comment: That's not particularly reusable.